# How can I make a span stay when I hover over an image with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code that works when I hover over the image but when I hover over the span it goes back to opacity 0. Also the span does not appear in the first image?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $img = $('.carousel-inner li img'),
            $text = $('.carousel-inner li span');

            $img.hover(function() {
                $text.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    height: '75px'
                }, 500);
                },function() {
                    $text.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    height: '0px'
                }, 500);
            });
    });
```

You can view an example [HERE](http://andres321r.byethost15.com/slideshow/)

Comment: don't hide it when you mouseout of the image. Obviously you want it to hide, so the better solution would be to move your hover up to the li rather than the img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.
Instead of

`var $img = $('.carousel-inner li img'),`

I put

```
var $img = $('.carousel-inner li')
```

I removed the `img` from the var so when I hover over the whole `li` my function worked instead of just hovering over the `img`.

But I still can't get the `span` to appear in the first image?

Comment: you probably want `$("span",this)` rather than `$text`

Comment: @KevinB The code is working for all other images except for the first one. The span appears with all images when hovered no problem, just does not appear on the first one. Could it be my carousel.js file?

Comment: I guess it could be anything at this point. I haven't visited your live demo because i only visit demos on jsfiddle, jsbin, codepen, or pastebin.

Comment: I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnAEk/2/) if you still want to have a look at it?

Comment: it seems to work for me, i see the correct span on each of the 4 images.

Comment: Really? Hmm that's weird than it must be my computer I guess??

Comment: It might be a browser difference. what browser are you testing in? I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m

Comment: I'm using firefox. Just tested it with chrome and the span animation works but not the slider. :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use the `$.hover()` function on the `<li>` (the container), not only the `<img>`.

```
var $li = $('.carousel-inner li')

...

$li.hover(function() { ... }
```

You can see the effect here: http://jsbin.com/EGOsuYi/1/

Comment: Yeah I figured that out my problem now is that the span does not appear on the first image for some weird reason. Made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnAEk/2/) if you want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You should address the wrapper of both like this:

```
$('.carousel-inner li').on('mouseenter',function() {
     //show text
});
$('.carousel-inner li').on('mouseleave',function() {
     //hide text
});
```